# Reading data from objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest, redux

I can't seem to figure out how to properly access and read this data set. I'm working with Django's REST API to pull a set of data from my back-end. This data is a series of quotes for my company. Afterwards it is passed through Redux to my react front end. I then need to look at each object in the array, go through its "attributes" and determine if one of them matches the value of a text field used to search the data.

I have googled for about 4 hours in the process of attempting different methods of accessing the data. This includes passing different levels to sorting functionality, and trying different methods of accessing the data.

Above the React component is this function

```
function filterItems(arr, query) {
  console.log(arr);
  return arr.filter(function(el) {
    return el.quotename.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
}
```

Inside of the component

```
            <TableBody>
              {console.log(this.props.quotes[0])}
              {stableSort(
                this.state.searchval
                  ? filterItems(
                      this.props.quotes["attributes"],
                      this.state.searchval
                    )
                  : this.props.quotes,
                getSorting(order, orderBy)
              )
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map(n => {
                  const isSelected = this.isSelected(n);
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={n.id}
                      selected={isSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
                        {n.attributes.quotenumber}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {n.attributes.quotedate.split("T")[0]}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {n.attributes.shipname}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {n.attributes.quotecustomer}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {n.attributes.quotecsr}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
```

Sample of JSON data

```
{
  quotes: {
    quotes: [
      {
        type: 'quotes',
        id: '11451',
        attributes: {
          quotenumber: 'I want to compare this string',
          quotedate: '2019-02-11T14:41:01.777000Z',
          quotecustomer: '100217',
          quotecsr: null,
          shipname: 'name',
          shipstate: 'state',
          quoteuser: 'user',
          quotemultiplier: 1
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'quotes',
        id: '34711',
        attributes: {
          quotenumber: '021511-4',
          quotedate: '2018-12-10T14:15:58.297000Z',
          quotecustomer: '100217',
          quotecsr: null,
          shipname: 'name',
          shipstate: 'state',
          quoteuser: 'user',
          quotemultiplier: 1
        }
      },
```

My state contains a `searchval` member that holds the current text field value. I need to filter my output array to only display objects whose 'quotenumber' field matches that search. For some reason I get a lot of issues where it tells me my sort is trying to access undefined data despite the console logging that the array index is very much there, and has the attributes. It's probably just a silly misunderstanding on my part of how that "attributes" section of the object needs accessed.

Comment: can you make a stackblitz with your desired input/output?

Comment: Not sure that I can considering the input is pulled from a locally hosted back-end. If I can better explain it let me know, but basically its an array of JSON objects and each of those objects contains attributes. I need to access a specific attribute and compare its value to a search field Edit: for clarification this would be very simple for me if it was simply local data. I've played around with this on a local array instead of the data loaded through my REST API and it's quite simple. It's the format of the JSON I believe to be throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

You can do filtering in `render` method in plain js, not jsx. This way you can use local (temporary) variables - they are far easier to debug - you can console.log them on different steps.

```
render() {
    const quotes = this.props.quotes["attributes"];
    const searchVal = this.state.searchval;
    const filtered = filterItems( quotes, searchVal );

    console.log( filtered );

    return (
      <TableBody>
```

Adapt code to your needs (f.e. passed props) and check values you're working on, f.e. probably there should be

```
    const quotes = this.props.quotes["quotes"];
    console.log( quotes ); // should be an array
```

but can be

```
    const quotes = this.props.quotes;
```

it all depends on api fetching, parrent to child props passing

Of course, assuming that this component is not rendered (by parent) without data - no undefined props passed in. In this case render conditionally `null`.

Comment: This throws back TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. 


within the filterItems function.

Comment: This helped a ton. It was not directly the answer I needed, but it led the way. I will post the full answer for those that are interested and to mark this as solved.